# Copying/pasting from an Excel file using Outlook VBA.

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Ok, so here I have a bit of conundrum. Here's the wordy version of what I am attempting:

1. In a template I've already made in Outlook, open it up and drag some files in - one of which will be an Excel file.
2. Open the Excel file and read to a predetermined last cell
3. Copy the cells from the last row/column to the first cell, `A1`.
4. Paste the cells previously copied in step 3 into the Outlook body

Number 4 is currently where my issues lie. Attached is the code

```
Const xlUp = -4162
'Needed to use the .End() method
 Sub Sample()
    Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Dim eAttachment As Object, xlsAttachment As Object, i As Integer, lRow As Integer, lPriorRow As Integer, lCommentRow As Integer

    '~~> Get the current open item
    Set NewMail = oInspector.CurrentItem
    'Code given to me from a previous question

    Set eAttachment = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With NewMail.Attachments
        For i = 1 To .Count

            If InStr(.Item(i).FileName, ".xls") > 0 Then
                'Save the email attachment so we can open it
                sFileName = "C:/temp/" & .Item(i).FileName
                .Item(i).SaveAsFile sFileName

                eAttachment.Workbooks.Open sFileName

                With eAttachment.Workbooks(.Item(i).FileName).Sheets(1)

                    lCommentRow = .Cells.Find("Comments").Row
                    lPriorRow = .Cells.Find("Prior Inspections").Row

                    lRow = eAttachment.Max(lCommentRow, lPriorRow)
                    ' Weirdly enough, Outlook doesn't seem to have a Max function, so I used the Excel one.

                    .Range("A1:N" & lRow).Select
                    .Range("A1:N" & lRow).Copy

                    'Here is where I get lost; nothing I try seems to work

                    NewMail.Display

                End With


                eAttachment.Workbooks(.Item(i).FileName).Close

                Exit For

            End If

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

I saw on another question a function that changes Range objects to HTML, but it doesn't work here since ***this Macro code is in Outlook, not Excel***.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail4.htm) will point you in the right direction.

---

### EDIT:

After some tinkering I got this to work:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Sample()
    Dim MyOutlook As Object, MyMessage As Object

    Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application, xlsAttachment As Attachment, wb As workBook, rng As Range

    Dim sFileName As String

    Dim lCommentRow As Long, lPriorRow As Long, lRow As Long

    ' Get the current open mail item
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set NewMail = oInspector.CurrentItem

    ' Get instance of Excel.Application
    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application

    ' Find the attachment
    For i = 1 To NewMail.Attachments.Count
        If InStr(NewMail.Attachments.Item(i).FileName, ".xls") > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Located attachment: """ & NewMail.Attachments.Item(i).FileName & """"
            Set xlsAttachment = NewMail.Attachments.Item(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Continue only if attachment was found
    If Not IsNull(xlsAttachment) Then

        ' Set temp file location and use time stamp to allow multiple times with same file
        sFileName = "C:/temp/" & Int(CDbl(Now()) * 10000) & xlsAttachment.FileName
        xlsAttachment.SaveAsFile (sFileName)

        ' Open file so we can copy info
        Set wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(sFileName)

        ' Search worksheet for important info
        With wb.Sheets(1)        
            lCommentRow = .Cells.Find("Comments").Row
            lPriorRow = .Cells.Find("Prior Inspections").Row
            lRow = excelApp.Max(lCommentRow, lPriorRow)
            set rng = .Range("A1:H" & lRow)
        End With

        ' Set up the email message
        With NewMail
            .To = "someone@organisation.com"
            .CC = "someoneelse@organisation.com"
            .Subject = "TEST - PLEASE IGNORE"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
            .Display
        End With

    End If
    wb.Close

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As workBook

    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8        ' Paste over column widths from the file
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        excelApp.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

You must go to Tools->References and include the Microsoft Excel Object Library.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729195/how-to-refer-to-excel-objects-in-access-vba) pointed me there.  I liked avoiding late binding so that the vba intellisense shows up and I know that the methods are valid.

RangetoHTML comes from [Ron Debruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) (I had to edit the PasteSpecial methods to get them to work)

I also got some help from [this forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628044-Insert-text-into-current-outlook-message&p=3891248#post3891248) on how to insert text into email body.

I added the date to the tempfile name because I was trying to save it multiple times.

I hope this helps.  I sure learned a lot!

### More Notes:

It appeared to me that the cells were being truncated.  As [mvsub1 explains here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/695489-ron-de-bruin-rangetohtml-adds-carriage-return-when-inserting-cell-range-into-message-body.html), The issue with using the function RangeToHTML is that it treats the text that exceeds the column width as hidden text and pastes it as such into the email:

```
[td class=xl1522522 width=64 style="width:48pt"]This cell i[span style="display:none">s too long.[/span][/td]
```

There are some solutions discussed on the page if you have a similar issue.

Comment: I want to try out the code myself, but cannot right now.  I will attempt to come back to it later!

Comment: I had found that, but it has the same issue of that looks to be going from Excel -> Outlook directly, whereas mine is more of an Outlook -> Open Excel/Read Data -> Copy to outlook. I say this mostly because I see them declare Range objects, yet when I try to do that in Outlook it gives me an error.

Comment: @Jhecht: Enable the reference to Microsoft Excel. The error might be caused by the reference not being enabled (I see that you are using late-binding in your code).

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself thinking that your code was in excel.

Comment: The error I get when I try to your exact code is `User-defined type not defined` it then highlights `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)`, Also @BK201, what do you mean?

Comment: On mobile so pardon if typos. The error might be thrown by the lack of reference to Excel. In the VBE, go to Tools > References and locate and enable the reference to MS Excel Object 12.0 or 14.0, can't remember which exactly. This should enable ptpaterson's code, assuming no other errors exist.

Comment: I have MS Excel 14.0 Object Library.  This is link to the definition of Range.  if you do not include this reference, the compiler will consider it to be a user-defined type.

Comment: *****this links to the definition of Range***** - the grammar nazi.

Comment: Will try this when I get home, currently unable to check. If it works, will mark your answer.

Comment: I'm using Office 2003, do you think that will make a difference?

Comment: I think it should.  Although I am using 2010, the code I used from Ron Debruin says "working for Office 2000-2013". Let's hope the other references hold up.  Please let me know if you are still having problems.