# VBA email embed JPG not showing if I run the same macro on another device

Tags: vba, outlook

I just wrote a macro for copy and paste certain range in Excel file to Outlook in jpg format based on this (https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-vba-paste-range-into-email-body/). It works fine on my computer, but once I try to run it on my colleague's device, the jpg file will become a red cross:

```
Sub PasteRangeinMail()
Dim FilePath As String
Dim Outlook As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Dim HTMLBody As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastday As String

Worksheets("X").Activate

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("A1:J" & lastrow)

With Application
.Calculation = xlManual
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Outlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set OutlookMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Call createImage(ActiveSheet.Name, rng.Address, "RangeImage")
FilePath = "Y"

lastday = Format(Date - 2, "DD MMMM YYYY")

HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
& "<p class=style1><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Times New Roman SIZE=4>" _
& "Dear All,<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& "PLACEHOLDER" & lastday & ":<br> " _
& "<br>" _
& "<img src=RangeImage.jpg>" _
& "<br>" _
& "<br>Regards, <br><br> PLACEHOLDER</font></span>"

With OutlookMail
.Subject = "PLACEHOLDER" & lastday
.HTMLBody = HTMLBody
.Attachments.Add FilePath & "RangeImage.jpg", olByValue
.To = "xxx@xxx.com "
.CC = "yyy@yyy.com"
.Display
.Save
.Send
End With

End Sub


Sub createImage(SheetName As String, rngAddrss As String, nameFile As String)
Dim rngJpg As Range
Dim Shape As Shape
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
Set rngJpg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(rngAddrss)
rngJpg.CopyPicture
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects.Add(rngJpg.Left, rngJpg.Top, rngJpg.Width, rngJpg.Height)
.Activate
For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
Shape.Line.Visible = msoFalse
Next
.Chart.Paste
.Chart.Export "XXXX\YYYY" & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
End With
Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
Set rngJpg = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I display the email on my colleague's device before sending it, the file will show properly, but if I skip the step and send it directly, red cross will show up.

I want to make this macro able to run on any device.

Comment: You need to use a `cid` - Does this answer your question? [How to embed an image into an Outlook email using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617458/how-to-embed-an-image-into-an-outlook-email-using-vba)

Comment: I add cid in line
& "<img src=RangeImage.jpg>" _
and it still doesn't work, thanks for answering.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751713/copying-pasting-from-an-excel-file-using-outlook-vba

Comment: In addition to adding cid, you'll need to add quotes `& "<img src=""cid:RangeImage.jpg"">" _`