# Getting the number of rows in a table with Access VBA without using an Excel Reference

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to edit an Excel file from MS Access without using Excel as a reference. I found an answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729195/how-to-refer-to-excel-objects-in-access-vba) that helps with this problem. Instead of using references to Excel, I use Objects. This seems to work for the most part, but I don't get all the functions I need from Excel in order to count the rows on a table. A snippet of my code is as follows:

```
    Dim xlBook As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlSht As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Some\Location.xlsx")
    Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets("SomeSheet")

    tableRows = xlSht.Cells(xlSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

I get an error on the `tableRows = xlSht...` line which reads:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error
```

I've tried numerous different ways of fixing this problem, such as rewriting the line, changing the sheetnames. I can't seem to find any documentation on this scenario. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If it's on your activesheet try this: `activesheet.cells(activesheet.rows.count, 2).end(xlup).row` I've had the same problem more then once, referencing not to the variables you've set, but directly to the object fixed it for me
Otherwise try something as `activeworkbook.sheet("Somesheet").cells(activeworkbook.sheet("Somesheet".rows.count, 2).end(xlup).row` I know it's not pretty, but it works. At least it did for me

Comment: What happens if you replace `xlUp` with `-4162`?

Comment: I agree with HansUp ... xlUp is a constant defined in Excel. If you don't have a reference to the object library and work with so called late binding, you have to declare/replace this constants by yourself. PS: as very often ... OPTION EXPLICIT on top of the module would give you a clear indication for the problem.

Comment: As cboden said - you'll have to replace your constants.  The easiest way I've found to do this is open Excel and, for example, type `?xlUp` into the VBE Immediate window - this will return the number you need.

Comment: @HansUp, that was the issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a reference to the Excel type library, the Excel named constant `xlUp` is unknown to Access VBA.

You could avoid the error supplying the constant's value, -4162, instead of the constant's name.  Or define the constant in your VBA code ...

```vb
Const xlUp As Long = -4162
```

As [@cboden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4186108/cboden) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999894/getting-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-with-access-vba-without-using-an-excel-ref?noredirect=1#comment55756791_33999894), include `Option Explicit` in the Declarations section of your code module.  Then when you run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu, it will alert you about any similar issues with unrecognized names.