# Generating a formatted Excel datasheet from Access data

Tags: ms-access, excel

The title basically sums up my question. Essentially I'd like to generate a formatted excel sheet from access table data with the click of a button in my form. I know you can export access data to excel, but is there a way to generate an excel sheet that is formatted? Is there some excel scripting language that I can execute through VBA being fed the data from my access DB?

A few specifics about the DB:

- It simply tracks employee counts at certain positions within a company. So that's incoming employees, employees being redeployed, employees being terminated, employees being transferred, etc.
- The goal is to be able to create an excel staffing plan from this data.

If there's anything else I can provide please let me know!
Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but maybe try opening a template file with the formatting you want (rather than a blank, new file) to put your data into?

Comment: You can access the complete [excel application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff194565.aspx) like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729195/how-to-refer-to-excel-objects-in-access-vba).