# vba- If else statement within a for loop

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'd like to add the following that deletes row that contains 0

```
    If Cells(intFile, "CU") = "0" Then           
        Sheet1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete    
    End If
```

to my code below.

```
   If CDate(rst(3)) >= Date Then

       For intCount = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
           strHold = strHold & rst(intCount).Value & "|"
```

Currently on 'Cells' `ElseIf Cells(intFile, "CU") = "0" Then` 
I'm getting compile error: sub or function not defined.
what should i put instead of `Cells`?

My reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: Function invocations are analyzed along with the passed arguments (search for **overloading** concept). I guess that you are calling the right function with the wrong set of arguments.

Comment: Is this [access-vba] or [excel-vba]?  You are using `CurrentDB` which is MSAccess VBA, and `Cells` which is Excel VBA.

Comment: what is the value of `FreeFile` ? since `intFile = FreeFile` and later you check if `ElseIf Cells(intFile, "CU") = "0" Then`

Comment: @YowE3K seems to be right. Most likely you are trying to use Excel's Cells function without a reference to Excel.

Comment: Wait - I recognise the line that says `If CDate(rst(3)) >= Date Then`!  This is Access - I answered a question that recommended that line be entered.

Comment: @YowE3K  you can tell it is access due to the Option Compare Database statement at the top, User needs to add the reference then fully qualify the Excel Object - Also it looks like the user is opening a csv file but not using Excel to do so but openingit as a text file: Open strFilePath For Output As #intFile

Comment: it is access-vba @YowE3K apologies for the confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer to Excel objects in Access VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729195/how-to-refer-to-excel-objects-in-access-vba)

Comment: If you are trying to not write the record if `rst(98) = 0` then modify the previous line to be `If CDate(rst(3)) >= Date And rst(98) <> 0 Then`

Comment: @cyboashu nope sorry never seen it before

Comment: @YowE3K will try that now! and please create an answer so that i can approve it! :)

Comment: @JohnTipton  That is not going to solve the issue.  Your problem is that you are referencing excel objects but have not created an Excel Application and workbook object.  You then try and reference Sheets and Cells.   Are  you Familiar with adding in a reference?

Comment: @Sorceri I see what you are talking about. yes I do. Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: @Sorceri - John isn't trying (intentionally) to reference Excel objects - he's just trying to not write out certain records to the csv file he is creating, but has used Excel functionality to do it instead of Access functionality.  The lines referencing `Cells` and `Sheet1` are new lines that have been added, which should have just been done using an amendment to the `If` statement preceding it.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks! and I haven't not tested yet.. in the middle of making a fake file to test it out. as we don't have a back order yet. thank you in advance! please leave an answer below!

Comment: "back order" - your previous code was excluding any records where the date was prior to today.  Your new code will exclude all of those, and **also** exclude any others where field 98 is zero.  Is that what you want?  Or are you trying to **not** exclude some of the ones where the date is prior to today?

Comment: @YowE3K Correct, for the former! For now :) Thanks for a very good question :) You are truly amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that there are many "flavours" of Visual Basic, and they aren't interchangeable.

Your application is running in MSAccess, and it will have certain objects, functions, etc, that are specifically applicable to that environment.  The `Cells` object is something that is specifically applicable to the MS Excel environment and therefore Access VBA has no understanding of what a `Cells` object is.

(And the documentation you referred to is regarding the syntax for VB.Net - but the specific topic you were looking at **is** treated the same in all these different versions of "Visual Basic".  But it does appear from that web page that the `Then` in an `If` statement is an optional keyword in VB.Net, while it is required in VBA, so there's one difference on even such an elementary piece of coding.)

If you change your code from

```
If CDate(rst(3)) >= Date Then
ElseIf Cells(intFile, "CU") = "0" Then
    Sheet1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
```

to be

```
If CDate(rst(3)) >= Date And rst(98) <> 0 Then
```

I believe you will be doing what you set out to do, i.e. exclude all records where the 4th field (`3` due to zero-base) is before today and also exclude all records where the 99th field is 0.